# remove elements from a knockout.js observable array with javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, knockout.js

I have called a function and populated my array which is fine, I now want to loop through the array and remove any elements where the value of the 'Name' field occurs more than once in the array (ie more than one record with the same value for 'Name') an where a HubID field is null.

Can anyone provide an example?

thanks

Comment: Is it a Knockout Observable Array? An example of the code you've got so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `arrayGetDistinctValues` knockout utility function to get an array of all the unique product names.

```
self.uniqueNames = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var arrayOfNames = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Products(), function(item){ return item.Name})
    return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(arrayOfNames).sort();
});
```

You can filter an array using the knockout `arrayFilter` utility to select a certain subset of items from the array. In this example where HubID is not null.

```
self.filteredProducts = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.Products(), function(item) {
         return item.HubID != null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be something along these lines

```
self.count = ko.computed(function (_name) {
            var countedItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Products(), function (arrayItem) {
                return arrayItem.Name == _name;
            });
            return countedItems.length;
        });
```